# C# keywords spotting in real time (continues speech) - voice commands

Tags: c#, voice-recognition, voice

I'm looking for an easy way to catch some commands in real time. For instance:

an user talks with friends through skype or something and unexpectedly says:
`Computer, command one six four end` and the program will automatically get that he must do some actions that have been predefined by user and assigned to text: "command one six four".

"command one six four" or other sentences would be recorded by user so there is no need for speech recognition, just a sentence spotting.

I've read about cmusphinx but in my opinion it's a bit too big thing for this purpose. Please, tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Windows (desktop, mobile, even IoT) already includes speech recognition. Did you check it?

Comment: Matching a recording is actually much more difficult than speech recognition. Think about background noise or other ambient sounds. It would require filtering out both the original recording and the current input stream and trying pattern matching. Just go with speech recognition.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I didn't know

Comment: CMUSphinx is exactly the thing for your task. Windows speech recognition can not spot keywords.